# Native ContextMenu c#

Tags: c#, c++, winforms, pinvoke, native

Is there a way to set ContextMenuStrip to be rendered as native ContextMenu?

Comment: You may be using the `SystemRenderer`

Comment: what do you mean saying "native" ?

Comment: I think he meant the look the ContextMenuStrip in the Windows the program is being run..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the toolstrip renderers that are available, ToolStripSystemRenderer in particular, tried to emulate the native Windows look but the programmers didn't have a time machine to guess what they would look like in Windows 7.  Winforms is in maintenance mode, the class isn't going to get updated.

If you want the native Windows look then use the ContextMenu class instead.  Add it to the toolbox by right-clicking it and selecting "Choose items".